# UIBezierPath addLine: wrong length uppon draw

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

Given is a UIBezierPath which should be "dashed" and added to a view as a sublayer:

```
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.8
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [7, 7]
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: .zero)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width, y: 0)) // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    shapeLayer.path = path
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    view.backgroundColor = .yellow
```

The problem is, that the dashed line is not equal to the width of the "view":
[image]

The yellow is the background color of the view itself. The dashed line is the created UIBezierPath.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Where is this code (what class and method)? My guess is you are doing this in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` of a view controller. The controller's view size isn't set yet in those methods.

Comment: simple as that... thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles on this problem:

As @rmaddy said, the problem was that this function was being called in `viewWillAppear`. Where the size has not been properly initialized yet.
Calling the same function in `viewDidAppear` solved the problem.